# State of parent component passed to child component is undefined

Tags: reactjs

In my parent component, I have a function that makes a GET request. I store the response JSON in the state of the parent component and pass the state to the child component which then renders the response in a particular format (in this, it populates a table).

This is the code of the parent component:-

```
ParentComponent { 
   sendGETRequest() {
    /* Fetch API code */
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(response => {
            this.setState({
                    personData: response
            });
            console.log(this.state.personData); //loads late 
    });
   }

   render() {
      return(
      <Link to="/PersonData/ViewPerson">
      <input onClick={this.sendGETRequest} />

      <Route
            path="/PersonData/ViewPerson"
            render={() => <ViewPersonTable pData={this.state.personData} />}
      />
    );
   }
}
```

This is the code of the child component:-

```
ChildComponent{
    render(){
       console.log(this.props.pData); //This loads before the console.log in parent and is undefined 
       return(
       );
     }
 }
```

My problem is that, from what I can tell, the setState takes place after the child component has already been rendered and so the state I'm passing to the child component is 'undefined'. How do I fix this?

Comment: You may have to set an initial state to `personData` or render the child only when `personData` is available..

Comment: @Panther when I print the state in the parent component, it works. The moment I pass the state to the child component and try printing it there, I get 'undefined'

Comment: I think, you have forgotten that `setState` is `async`. When we call `setState`, there is no guarente that the immediate `console.log` would show the new state. One may use the callback in setstate to see if you need so

Comment: Also since the fetch call is async,, the child component would render if your route matches. So your child component is expected to render before the fetch completes and hence you would receive the undefined in the child component. But if you conditionally render the component based on the completion of the fetch, you would get the expected answer i beleive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do with conditional render;

```
  <Route
        path="/PersonData/ViewPerson"
        render={() => this.state.personData ? <ViewPersonTable pData={this.state.personData} /> : null}
  />
```